# How can I use one Android device as mouse and keyboard input for another Android device via bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, keyboard, mouse

I've already seen lots of ways to do this for Windows PCs, but is there a way I can do the same thing but for another Android device?

Comment: How do you think about mouse control when there's no mouse pointer in Android device you want to control?

Comment: @SachinShekhar: Android from v3.1 and up (at least) supports mouse input and a pointer ([one reference](http://www.eurodroid.com/2011/05/10/google-announces-android-3-1-usb-connectivity-mouse-input-and-more/)).

Comment: @eldarerathis I once encountered mouse pointer in Android on Asus netbook (Android was as in-built micro-OS instance for quick surfing etc). I assumed that it was a tweak applied by Asus.
But, no.. its officially supported. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[image: Serverless Bluetooth Keyboard & Mouse for PC/Phone]

Serverless Bluetooth Keyboard & Mouse for PC/Phone should be what you're looking for. I hope this helps. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.appground.blek

Comment: As of Dec 2022, I can confirm this works flawlessly.

Comment: In my experience, it works - but the Bluetooth connection between my devices appears kind of flaky (an experience I didn't have with a dedicated BT keyboard and mice) and the result is a very poor typing or mousing experience. I was using the app on a Pixel device to connect to a Lenovo device, so it's not about poor hardware.

Answer (score 1):

[Android Mouse and Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iandrobot.andromouse.lite) might be able to do what you want. Install it on one device, use it in bluetooth mode, and then sync that device's virtual bluetooth keyboard and mouse to the other device just as you would a real bluetooth keyboard or mouse.

Comment: That is a great app, but requires a desktop server to be running :-(

Comment: This app isn't compatible with Android 13.